# Are there any difference in these two phrases: a team of 13 people, and 13 people without a team of

Tags: difference, word-in-context

Our new cake shop has 13 staff, including our boss 
(1 boss, 1 manager, 2 assistant managers, 2 bakers, 1 cook, 2 senior shop assistants, 4 shop assistants)

In my diary, I have written this:

> The shop manager, nickname, is a nice person, he works with a team of
>   12 people to make the shop function well and delight the customers
>   with delicious cakes.

I am thinking to erase the three works, "a team of" from the sentence. 
Originally, I thought the use of the three words could make a strong feeling that we worked together happily.
Should I leave it alone or the meaning will change if I erase the three words from the sentence?

> The shop manager, nickname, is a nice person, he works with 12 people to make the shop function well and delight the customers
>   with delicious cakes.

Comment: [*team*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/team) "1. a group of people organized to work together". There should be some beneficial reason for it, but there is no requirement that everyone is happy. But "happy" people tend to work together, while "unhappy" people don't. So using *team* in your example depends on how important the "happiness" is in context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a huge difference between:

> he works with 12 people

and

> he works with a team of 12 people

Adding "a team of" would imply at least a degree of working together that omitting it would not. In particular, if he worked with these 12 people independently and they didn't work with each other than adding "team of" would be misleading.